# Open a custom Intent when click on notification for Firebase notification payload

Tags: firebase, push-notification, notifications, payload, firebase-notifications

When click on a notification it should be open a custom Intent for Firebase notification payload.

> click_action  returns null when set any Intent name

So, is it possible to set an Intent on click of a notification.

Answer (score 2):

> click_action: Indicates the action associated with a user click on the
>   notification. When this is set, an activity with a matching intent
>   filter is launched when user clicks the notification.

So you have to add intent filter to your activity in manifest file.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="clikcActionNameHere"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: on which attribute, its need to add a matching intent filter? do you give an exmple?

Comment: @Newton example added.